# Trouble with easy_install cheetah on WIndows Xp

Tags: python, cheetah

I have installed PyQT from this URL:

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.6-gpl-4.7.7-1.exe

I have Python 2.6 installed.

My OS is Windows XP SP3.

I entered this into cmd.exe:

```
easy_install cheetah
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users>easy_install cheetah
Searching for cheetah
Best match: cheetah 2.4.3
Processing cheetah-2.4.3-py2.6.egg
cheetah 2.4.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing cheetah-script.py script to C:\Python26\Scripts
Installing cheetah.exe script to C:\Python26\Scripts
Installing cheetah.exe.manifest script to C:\Python26\Scripts
Installing cheetah-compile-script.py script to C:\Python26\Scripts
Installing cheetah-compile.exe script to C:\Python26\Scripts
Installing cheetah-compile.exe.manifest script to C:\Python26\Scripts

Using c:\python26\lib\site-packages\cheetah-2.4.3-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for cheetah
Searching for Markdown>=2.0.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Markdown/
Reading http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/
Reading http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown
Reading https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=153041
Best match: Markdown 2.0.3
Downloading http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-markdown/files/markdown/2.0.3
/Markdown-2.0.3.win32.exe/download
Processing download
error: Couldn't find a setup script in c:\docume~1\admini~1\locals~1\temp\easy_i
nstall-awtoum\download

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting on *'awtoum'* is probably for the **[Autumn-ORM](http://autumn-orm.org/)**, which you can probably install with the command `easy_install autumn`. Once you have that prerequisite working, you can give the Cheetah installation another try, and it should skip right on past the error if the Autumn-ORM is already installed.

Alternately, you might have better luck installing via pip (which, perhaps ironically, you can install with the command `easy_install pip`). With pip, running `pip install cheetah` will try to get the latest version and all prerequisites/dependencies).

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it next time I get to the lab in college and if it works, I will accept your answer.